# Conversion Tracking on 3rd party Website using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have the following scenario: Website A contains product description and links to the booking website B where the user places his order.

I need to track conversions placed on the website B and have them displayed in the Google Analytics account of the website A (which I control). Website A is owned by me, website B is a 3rd party website but I can have their webmaster insert tags in their GTM.

Both websites use GTM for analytics tracking code. So far I have cross domain tracking setup.

#### Website A

- Cookie-Domain: auto
- allowLinker: true
- autoLinkDomains contains domain of the website B

#### Website B

- Cookie-Domain: auto
- allowLinker: true
- autoLinkDomains contains domain of the website A

In GA account of the website A I have added the domain of the website B to the referral exclusion list. So far good, the links on the website A are being decorated with the linker parameters so the website be receives the client ID.

I didn't find any explanation of how I should now report the conversions which are done on the website B to the google Analytics account of the Website A. I only want to report the conversions for which the Website A accounts because the Website B has many other traffic sources!

How can this be achieved? As said I can have webmaster of the website B to configure their GTM tags accordingly when I know what to configure there.